# Nested chapter name dictionary builder using chapter number and name information

Tags: python, nested-loops

I am trying to build a function that takes chapter numbers information and corresponding chapter name information to get out a dictionary that contains information about the chapter name organization according to the chapter number inputs.

Following is an example.

```
A = ['1.1.', '1.1.1.', '1.1.1.1.', '1.1.1.2.', '1.2.', '1.3.']
B = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

C = some_function(A, B)
```

Then C should be

```
{'a':{'b':{'c': [], 'd': []}}, 'e': [], 'f': []}
```

Could you please help me to figure this out?

Comment: What exactly was the difficulty you encountered?

Comment: I was having a hard time to generalize it..it looks like it’s nesting function implementation problem but not sure...